# Django 1.9 url include AttributeError 'str' object has no attribute 'regex'

Tags: django, django-urls

I recently upgraded from Django 1.7 to 1.9, and having some trouble converting the urls with includes.

I get the error message: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'regex'

urls.py files below:

**myapp/urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from myapp.views import IndexView

#app_name = 'myapp'

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
]
```

**mysite/urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),

  # Have also tried the following combinations
  #url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls', 'myapp')),
  #url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls'), name='myapp'),

  # This one works
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mysite/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "lib/python3.5/site-packages/Django-1.9.1-py3.5.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "lib/python3.5/site-packages/Django-1.9.1-py3.5.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "lib/python3.5/site-packages/Django-1.9.1-py3.5.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "lib/python3.5/site-packages/Django-1.9.1-py3.5.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    self.check()
  File "lib/python3.5/site-packages/Django-1.9.1-py3.5.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "lib/python3.5/site-packages/Django-1.9.1-py3.5.egg/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "lib/python3.5/site-packages/Django-1.9.1-py3.5.egg/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 10, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "lib/python3.5/site-packages/Django-1.9.1-py3.5.egg/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    warnings.extend(check_resolver(pattern))
  File "lib/python3.5/site-packages/Django-1.9.1-py3.5.egg/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 27, in check_resolver
    warnings.extend(check_pattern_startswith_slash(pattern))
  File "lib/python3.5/site-packages/Django-1.9.1-py3.5.egg/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 63, in check_pattern_startswith_slash
    regex_pattern = pattern.regex.pattern
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'regex'
```

Comment: http://myhost.tld/myapp/

Comment: The stack trace above came from running on the command line, but I do get the same error trying to launch the test server.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't you import `include` as well here `from django.conf.urls import url, include` ? I mean instead of having `import`, you should have `include`, I think.

Answer (score 2):

I had a block of code commented out as a string in myapp/urls.py which was causing the issue:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from myapp.views import IndexView

#app_name = 'myapp'

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),

  '''

  ...some old code from the Django 1.7.6 config

  '''
]
```

Django is attempting to read the string as a url object, which was causing the error.

Removing the string fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
```

instead

```
from django.conf.urls import url, import
```

Comment: That was a typo from when I copied in the text. Fixed it above, thanks!